# HQL query with inner join and check for NULL fails

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I need to select all customer records that has linked rental entity that has field `return_date` that is null. The following SQL query works:

```
 SELECT
     c.customer_id, r.rental_id
     FROM
     Customer c
     INNER JOIN rental as r
     ON (c.customer_id = r.customer_id)
     WHERE r.return_date IS NULL;
```

Why following HQL is not working:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Customer customer " +
                        "inner join customer.rentals as r " +
                        "where r.return_date is null");
```

Context:

```
@Override
    public List<Customer> getFilteredCustomers(String filter) {
        Session session = null;
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                Query query = session.createQuery("select customer from Customer customer " +
                        "join customer.rentals r " +
                        "where r.return_date is null");
                customers = (List<Customer>)query.list(); // << BREAKPOINT A
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }finally {
                if (session!=null) session.close();
            }
        return customers;
    }
```

Solution:

Apparently, the name of fields used in HQL must be taken from model classes but not from database...

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select c " +
                        " from Rental r, Customer c " +
                        " where r.customer = c " +
                        " and r.returnDate is null");
```

Comment: I've updated my answer after your context added. Try and tell me if it's ok. If no, please post the error

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't work because you try to link customer with a collection (rentals) but to access on return_date you must point the i-esime element of your collection, so you can invert your query, starting by `RENTAL` object (I hope you have mapped it)

Try this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select c " +
           " from Rental r, Customer c " +
           " where r.customer_id = c.customer_id " +
           " and r.return_date is null");
```

Comment: first one is not applicable, second one does not work.

Comment: Please post the error of the second query? The first, why is not applicable?

Comment: but have you a Rental object?